# IOS Apple Watch voice input

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I plan to develop an application for Apple Watch. I need to implement a text input voice. On the official website I found the following method:

```
- (void)presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:(NSArray *)suggestions
                             allowedInputMode:(WKTextInputMode)inputMode
                                   completion:(void (^)(NSArray *results))completion
```

Interested in the following:

1. What languages are supported for input?
2. Is it possible to set the desired language programmatically?
3. Can I programmatically get the selected language?

Comment: This question is very broad. This site is intended for providing answers to concise questions related to specific programming issues/tools

Comment: @kris What's broad about it? It's three specific questions about a specific method in a specific SDK…

Comment: @AaronBrager I think that if you check this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic you will find that the question is too broad. This is not a specific programming question. You are asking about general features of an API/tool (1), best practices (2) and then finally about something that might be considered remotely related to actual programming (if that, 3). Hence "too broad"

Comment: @Kris I think I disagree with you, and I invite you to discuss further on [this Meta question I opened](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289581/1445366).

Comment: @AaronBrager I find this odd: this question can only be regarded as a clarification of watchkit, i.e. the API documentation of spec. This is not about the actual programming...

Comment: Broad? I have the same problem. It is clear these downvoters have no idea what is going on. These 3 questions are VERY relevant, and easy to answer for any expert in the topic.

Answer (score 1):

The input language for `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions` depends on the currently selected language of the selected keyboard on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

1. The user's system language is used as the input.
2. No, only the user can set the language.
3. Yes, you can see the user's selected language:

   ```
   NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject];
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response! So the voice input supports all languages or only the languages which are available in Siri?

Comment: Only the languages which Siri and iOS dictation support. There's a [list here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204389), with Danish, Dutch, English (India), English (New Zealand), Portuguese (Brazil), Russian, Swedish, Thai, and Turkish coming in iOS 8.3.

Comment: Thank you. Then arises the question of your reply. How to get programmatically the selected language in Siri?

Comment: @IlyaSuvorov See my answer to #3. This is the language used to interpret text input for this method.

Comment: This method returns the system language but not the language of Siri?

Comment: The system language is used to interpret the response to `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:allowedInputMode: completion:`.

Comment: In fact, your system language can be english, but if your keyboard is in German, then Dictation will be analyzed in German. Tried an true.